# SQL Server : select same colums count by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

Hi guys this is my table

```
L_Date
2013-05-14
2013-05-12
2013-05-13
2013-05-15
```

and I need now all dates and count result where L_Date is <= than the selected like:

```
L_Date          Count (<=)
2013-05-14        3
2013-05-12        1
2013-05-13        2
2013-05-15        4
```

Comment: try this  
select l_date,count(*) from table name where L_Date <= '' group by L_Date

Comment: First of all read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and please clearly explain your problem here. People here are to give answer not to research into your problem itself.

Comment: Is `L_Date` unique as per your example data? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: select 
    *, 
    (select COUNT(*) from YourTable b where b.L_Date<=a.L_Date) [Count (<=)] 
From YourTable a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select COUNT(*) from YourTable b where b.L_Date<=a.L_Date) [Count (<=)] 
From YourTable a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following query also -

```
SELECT t_1.l_Date, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT Distint l_Date FROM Your_Table_Name) t_1,
       Your_Table_Name t_2
 WHERE t_2.l_Date <= t_1.l_Date
 GROUP BY t_1.l_Date
```

This will group by date and will give one row for one date value.